# What is phase sensitive detection?

Tags: electronics

The lock-in amplifier is said to have a phase sensitive detector which compares the phases of the reference and incoming signal and is thus able to recover a weak signal from an overwhelming background noise. I find this phase sensitive detection mathematical and am unable to understand the physics behind it. What exactly is *phase sensitive detection*?

This video gives a good idea about the lock in amplifier, but the again, I find it all abstract.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZIjBRA2S0NQ

Comment: I am also very interested in your question but i do not think you will find answers here

Comment: Do you want to understand how it is accomplished in a real lock-in, or abstractly (although you say you understand the math)?

Comment: this may help: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/369235/effect-of-lock-in-amplifier-phase-noise/369244#369244

Comment: @JonCuster What I understand is, there is some multiplication of sin terms which results in terms like cos(fs-fr) and cos (fs+fr) (fs and fr being the frequencies of  the  incoming and reference signals respectively). When fs=fr, the cos(fs-fr)  becomes 1 and the other additive term is got rid of by a low pass filter.  So the  output signal is proportional to the input signal only.

Comment: suggest you ask this question on the amateur radio stack exchange.